# Entity Framework using context in static services MVC5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have made an application that uses SignalR to occasionally fetch new data and show it to the users in real time. The problem is that my services are static (in my case I have named them Utilities) and inconsistently I receive errors which lead me to thinking that I have a concurrency problem with the context. Logically my services are best to be static. Here's my code, can you suggest me a better design pattern or something so I can still have my services static, but don't run into the errors from concurrent EF usage.

This is where I give each of my static services a DbContext to work with:

```
public static class Common
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static CryptoStatisticsDbContext _dbcontext;

    internal static CryptoStatisticsDbContext DbContext => _dbcontext ?? (_dbcontext = new CryptoStatisticsDbContext());
}
```

Here are some of my services

`TickerUtility`

```
public static class TickerUtility
{
    public delegate void UpdateTickerDelegate(int currencyId, decimal bid, decimal ask);

    public static event UpdateTickerDelegate TickerUpdatedEvent;

    public static List<Ticker> LastTickers { get; private set; } = new List<Ticker>();

    public static IList<Ticker> GetAllTickers(Action<Ticker> actionToDoWithEachTicker)
    {
        var tickers = new ConcurrentBag<Ticker>();

        var allCurrencies = Common.DbContext.Currencies.Include(c => c.Market).ToList();

        Parallel.ForEach(allCurrencies, currency =>
        //foreach (var currency in allCurrencies)
        {
            var ticker = GetTicker(currency);
            tickers.Add(ticker);
            actionToDoWithEachTicker?.Invoke(ticker);
        });


        return tickers.ToList();
    }
}
```

`MarketUtility`

```
public static class MarketUtility
{
    public static List<Market> Get()
    {
        return Common.DbContext.Markets.Include(m => m.Currencies).ToList();
    }
}
```

`SignalRUtility`

```
public static class SignalRUtility
{
    private static readonly IHubContext PublicMarketsHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PublicMarketsHub>();
    private static readonly IHubContext AdminMarketsHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AdminMarketsHub>();

    public static void SendNewTickersToClients(object state)
    {
        TickerUtility.GetAllTickers(ticker =>
        {
            if (ticker.IsVisibleForPublic)
                PublicMarketsHub.Clients.Group(ticker.CurrencyId.ToString()).addNewTicker(ticker);

            AdminMarketsHub.Clients.Group(ticker.CurrencyId.ToString()).addNewTicker(ticker);

        });
    }

    public static void UpdateBalances(object state)
    {
        BalancesUtility.GetAvailableBalances(balance => AdminMarketsHub.Clients.All.showBalanceForMarket(balance),
            (market) => AdminMarketsHub.Clients.All.showError($"Error getting {market} balances")
        );
    }
}
```

The BackgroundTimer which calls the static functions

```
public class BackgroundServerTimer : IRegisteredObject
{
    private Timer ratesTimer;
    private Timer balancesTimer;

    private readonly TimeSpan ratesTimerInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20);
    private readonly TimeSpan balancesTimerInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 60);

    public BackgroundServerTimer()
    {
        StartTimers();
    }

    private void StartTimers()
    {
        var delayStartby = new TimeSpan(0,0,0, 1);

        ArbitrageUtility.AttachListenerToTickerChanges();

        ratesTimer = new Timer(SignalRUtility.SendNewTickersToClients, null, delayStartby, ratesTimerInterval);
        balancesTimer = new Timer(SignalRUtility.UpdateBalances, null, delayStartby, balancesTimerInterval);
    }


    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        ratesTimer.Dispose();
        balancesTimer.Dispose();

        HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
    }
}
```

To elaborate on my problem see my HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var markets = MarketUtility.Get().Select(m =>
        {
            m.Currencies = m.Currencies.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList();
            return m;
        });

        var isUserAdmin = User.IsInRole("admin");
        if (!isUserAdmin)
        {
            markets = markets.Select(m =>
            {
                m.Currencies = m.Currencies.Where(c => c.IsVisibleForPublic).ToList();
                return m;
            }).ToList();
            markets = markets.Where(m => m.Currencies.Any()).ToList();
        }

        ViewBag.Markets = markets;

        return isUserAdmin ? View("AdminIndex") : View();
    }
}
```

One of my markets has 4 currencies. 2 public and 2 private. Sometimes when I view the app as a guest it shows me the 2 public, but after that I login with the admin but `MarketUtility.Get()` again returns me only the 2 public currencies (without me implying any .Where() clause). After some refreshes it gives me all 4 currencies. The same happens on edit and delete operations. I edit some entity (for example a currency) and the first couple of refreshes show different data. Sometimes the old data, sometimes the new data until (I suppose) EF clears it's cache and then I start to get the fresh data. I have disabled LazyLoading and ProxyCreation, now the problems occurs more rarely, but I know this is not the solution.

```
Parallel.ForEach(allCurrencies, currency =>
        //foreach (var currency in allCurrencies)
        {
            var ticker = GetTicker(currency);
            tickers.Add(ticker);
            actionToDoWithEachTicker?.Invoke(ticker);
        });
```

This is the line that throws exceptions like "Collection was Modified", "“The underlying provider failed on Open.” (this one I fixed using MARS, but again this is just a workaround). I don't get how can it throw collection was modified error when I use .ToList()
`var allCurrencies = Common.DbContext.Currencies.Include(c => c.Market).ToList();`

I want to make things the right way, to dispose the context when it's not needed, to consume less memory and everything, but still have my services static because it makes it easier for me (and I don't see a point in making them non static provided that all my methods are static

Comment: You should NEVER use a static DbContext.  In general, you should avoid static.

Comment: Well the thing that comes on my mind is to have `using (var context = new Context() {}` inside each and every method, but this doesn't sound ok..

Comment: That's exactly what you should be doing.  1. DbContext's hold onto objects you retrieve from the database by default, which can be detrimental in any multithreaded application (asp.net).  2. EF does not support multithreading, so if one thread make a db call, and another thread makes a db call, you'll get an exception on the second thread.

Comment: The most efficient way to use EF, in general, is to create a DbContext per *HttpRequest*.

Comment: This is new information for me. Thank you very much @ErikPhilips I'll make it that way

Comment: Since you need these per HttpRequest, you may want to look into using DI (my recommendation would be Autofac).

Comment: I've used Ninject and Unity, so I have an idea of DI. The thing I don't understand is how I'm going to use it? Wouldn't I just wrap all my method contents inside `using (var context = new Context() {}`? How will DI help me, how will I use it?

Comment: @Reath - If using DI, you *should* abandon the idea of making your services static and inject `DbContext` through the class constructor. Anything that requires dependencies such as `DbContext` should be in an instance class. A `DbContext` per static method may also work (though not ideal).

Comment: DI frameworks are the *logic* that can/should take care of the creation **and** disposal of objects.